# Long outputs manipulation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

does anyone know how to get the expressions of this shortened form? when I try to use "show all" my mathematica collapses

[image]

Comment: The expression is quite large (I.e., 318.3 MB). You should probably try to `Simplify` it using any known constraints on the variables as assumptions.  Simplification will likely be quite slow. I do not recommend that you try `FullSimplify` initially.

Answer (score 3):

**1.**

There is [Short](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html)

```
 Range[1000] // Short
```

[image]

```
Short[Range @ 1000, 2]
```

[image]

**2.**

And there is also [Shallow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shallow.html) with many options (consult documentation)

```
Shallow[Range @ 100]
```

[image]

**3.**

You should also look at [Iconize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are trying to extract or see the contents of the grey "...1..." and "...2...", etc. and not trying to make the result even more compact and hidden.

To see the actual contents and details after it displays all those grey blocks I use

```
InputForm[%]
```

Then I can scrape-n-paste parts or all of that into a text file and scrape out the bits that I want to use.

BUT I have never done that on a 318 megabyte expression, use with GREAT CAUTION.

Did I correctly guess what you were asking for? Thanks